# Get edge's default search engine using Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I am trying to get the default search engine in Edge using JavaScript but I am not getting how can I access the Edge Settings' info related to the default search engine.

I thank in advance for any type of info, help or guidance.

Comment: Where are you running this JS? An Edge Extension? Windows Scripting Host? Node.js? Somewhere else?

Comment: @Quentin : I am running this in an edge extension.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. (I work on the Edge team)